# Okta SDK Filter users with active status and using StartsWith and Contains keywords

Tags: c#, .net, okta

Does anyone have any example in .Net to search/filter user based on user's status (i.e. Active) and First/Last Name starting with a string?

The code snippet below is not working.

```
var filter = new FilterBuilder().Where(Core.Filters.User.Status)
.EqualTo(Core.Models.UserStatus.Active).And(new FilterBuilder().
Where(Core.Filters.User.LastName).StartsWith("J"));

foreach (Core.Models.User user in usersClient.GetFilteredEnumerator(filter))
{
    var test = user.Profile.LastName;
    var test2 = user.Profile.MobilePhone;
    // Do something with each user
}
```

Error:

```
ErrorCode: E0000031
ErrorID: oaeW2PeSC6_Tqy8exTTQSg7gg
ErrorSummary: Invalid search criteria.
ExceptionMessage: Exception of type 'Okta.Core.OktaException' was thrown.
Stack Trace:
   at Okta.Core.OktaExceptionResolver.ParseHttpResponse(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
   at Okta.Core.OktaHttpClient.Execute(HttpRequestType requestType, Uri uri, String relativeUri, String content, Int32 waitMillis, Int32 retryCount, Boolean bAddAuthorizationHeader)
   at Okta.Core.Clients.ApiClient`1.GetList(Uri nextPage, Int32 pageSize, FilterBuilder filter, SearchType searchType, String query, String after, Nullable`1 startDate)
   at Okta.Core.Clients.ApiClient`1.GetFilteredEnumerator(FilterBuilder filter, SearchType searchType, Int32 pageSize, String query, String after, Nullable`1 startDate)
   at Okta.Web.MvcApplication.Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\PoC\Okta\Okta.Web\Global.asax.cs:line 60
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Please format your code & question to be more readable

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you run into this issue is because the StartsWith operator is only available with our "Search" feature (http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#list-users-with-search), not our "Filter" feature (http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#list-users-with-a-filter) which is the default search type used in the C# SDK.

Please contact Okta's support team at http://support.okta.com if you would like to get your "Search" feature enabled in your Okta organization.